# Turning status codes to text in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, io

I'm using IO methods which return status codes

```
IOReturn returnVal;
returnVal = IOKitSomeFunction(...);

if (returnVal == kIOReturnNoDevice)
{
```

As seen in the sample it is possible to check if the code has a specific value - I'm searching for a way to "translate" the error code to a text.
(to make it NSLogable)

I'm sure there has to be a way but I'm not getting it.
Thanks!

Comment: If you know all possible status codes you could use a `NSDictionary`. The key would be the status code and the value the corresponding text. But: these won't be localized. You could also have a look into String files which can be localized. This could be done by using the status code as key (string) within the localized strings file (by using `NSLocalizedString()` function).

Comment: It's only for debugging porpose - the error codes are defined in https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.13.8/iokit/IOKit/IOReturn.h

Comment: Then a simple dictionary should be enough, I think. But these are a lot of them... Maybe you can read all of them programmatically, but I don't know if that's possible.